# Using a map of vectors of a derived class to call the its class's function

Tags: c++

Lets say I have this code:

```
class Parent{
public:
   virtual void printm(){
     cout << "Parent" << endl;
}

class Child:public Parent{
public:
   void printm(){
     cout << "Child" << endl;
}

int main()
{
Parent * aPerson = new Child;

map<string, vector<Parent*>> family;

family["Test"].pushback(aPerson);

//I want to be able to do SOMETHING like this but I'm wondering if that's  
//possible? I know it looks crazy but please bear with me

printdata(family["Test"]);
}

void printdata(Parent * x){
x->printm();
}
```

I've searched everywhere and haven't been able to find someone who has a similar problem to mine. I have a feeling it may be possible. I know it's much simpler to just do:

```
printdata(aPerson);
```

But..again...I just wanna know all the possibilities.

Comment: `family["Test"]` is not a Parent* or a Child* - it's a vector of Parent*s. It might contain several pointers, or none - in which case, what do you want to do?

Comment: I'm really slow.. If you're asking what I REALLY want to do: I simply want to call the printm() function using the map key. But as things are looking right now, I'm going to have to change some function parameters maybe?

Comment: You don't understand: the map does not contain pointers to parent classes. The map contains a vector of pointers to parent classes. This is how you declared the map. You have to decide what to do when: 1) the vector is empty, 2) the vector contains one pointer, and 3) the vector contains more than one pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`family["Test"]` evaluates to a `std::vector<Parent*>`. You can add a function overload:

```
void printdata(std::vector<Parent*> const& x)
{
   for(auto item : x )
   {
      printdata(item);
   }
}
```

Then,

```
printdata(family["Test"]);
```

should work.